# 2 errores de Valgrind Memcheck en función para calcular el IP checksum

Tags: c++

En esta función, hecha por Mike Muss, que funciona y es popular en la red, tengo 2 lecturas de zonas de memoria no reservadas que no consigo evitar:

```
 /*
 * compute an IP header checksum.
 * don't modify the packet.
 */
 static u_short IP_IN_CKSUM(const u_short *addr, register u_int len, int csum)
 {
  int nleft = len;
  const u_short *w = addr;
  u_short answer;
  int sum = csum;

  /*
   *  Our algorithm is simple, using a 32 bit accumulator (sum),
   *  we add sequential 16 bit words to it, and at the end, fold
   *  back all the carry bits from the top 16 bits into the lower
   *  16 bits.
   */
  while (nleft > 1)  {
    sum += *w++;//LÍNEA 799 ERROR: Invalid read of size 2!!!
    nleft -= 2;
  }
  if (nleft == 1)
    sum += htons(*(u_char *)w<<8);//LÍNEA 803 ERROR: Invalid read of size 1!!!

  /*
   * add back carry outs from top 16 bits to low 16 bits
   */
  sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);   /* add hi 16 to low 16 */
  sum += (sum >> 16);           /* add carry */
  answer = ~sum;                /* truncate to 16 bits */
  printf ("answer = %u\n", answer);
  return (answer);
  }
```

El log con el error de valgrind es:

```
==36720== Invalid read of size 2
==36720==    at 0x5BA3B0: IP_IN_CKSUM(unsigned short const*, unsigned int, int) (ip_proto.h:799)
==36720==    by 0x5BE8B2: UDP_CKSUM(unsigned char const*, udphdr const*, unsigned int) (ip_proto.h:970)
==36720==    by 0x5BD46A: dpisim::DPIsimPacket::computeChecksum_(unsigned char*, int) (DPIsimPacket.cc:990)
==36720==    by 0x5BD20E: dpisim::DPIsimPacket::computeChecksum() (DPIsimPacket.cc:939)
==36720==    by 0x5BB577: dpisim::DPIsimPacket::readPacket_(unsigned int) (DPIsimPacket.cc:349)
==36720==    by 0x5BB0D3: dpisim::DPIsimPacket::initialize(pcap_pkthdr const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int) (DPIsimPacket.cc:225)
==36720==    by 0x5BA5DB: dpisim::DPIsimPacket::DPIsimPacket(pcap_pkthdr const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int) (DPIsimPacket.cc:42)
==36720==    by 0x5DF70A: dpisim::DPIsimPacketManager::manipulatePacket(unsigned int, pcap_pkthdr*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int) (DPIsimPacketManager.cc:102)
==36720==    by 0x5ADFE4: dpisim::DPIsimTracePcap::run() (DPIsimTracePcap.cc:134)
==36720==    by 0x5DED12: boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>::operator()(dpisim::DPIsimTrace*) const (mem_fn_template.hpp:49)
==36720==    by 0x5DEBB5: void boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<dpisim::DPIsimTrace*> >::operator()<boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>, boost::_bi::list0>(boost::_bi::type<void>, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>&, boost::_bi::list0&, int) (bind.hpp:255)
==36720==    by 0x5DEAE8: boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<dpisim::DPIsimTrace*> > >::operator()() (bind_template.hpp:20)
==36720==  Address 0x7df53a0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 48 alloc'd
==36720==    at 0x4A08982: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:385)
==36720==    by 0x5BB02C: dpisim::DPIsimPacket::initialize(pcap_pkthdr const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int) (DPIsimPacket.cc:215)
==36720==    by 0x5BA5DB: dpisim::DPIsimPacket::DPIsimPacket(pcap_pkthdr const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int) (DPIsimPacket.cc:42)
==36720==    by 0x5DF70A: dpisim::DPIsimPacketManager::manipulatePacket(unsigned int, pcap_pkthdr*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int) (DPIsimPacketManager.cc:102)
==36720==    by 0x5ADFE4: dpisim::DPIsimTracePcap::run() (DPIsimTracePcap.cc:134)
==36720==    by 0x5DED12: boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>::operator()(dpisim::DPIsimTrace*) const (mem_fn_template.hpp:49)
==36720==    by 0x5DEBB5: void boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<dpisim::DPIsimTrace*> >::operator()<boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>, boost::_bi::list0>(boost::_bi::type<void>, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>&, boost::_bi::list0&, int) (bind.hpp:255)
==36720==    by 0x5DEAE8: boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<dpisim::DPIsimTrace*> > >::operator()() (bind_template.hpp:20)
==36720==    by 0x5DEA63: boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<dpisim::DPIsimTrace*> > > >::run() (thread.hpp:116)
==36720==    by 0x608DD49: thread_proxy (in /lab/dpi/building-deps/boost/boost_1_59_0/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.59.0)
==36720==    by 0x3D45807AA0: start_thread (in /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so)
==36720==    by 0x3D454E893C: clone (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==36720== 
==36720== Invalid read of size 1
==36720==    at 0x5BA3CD: IP_IN_CKSUM(unsigned short const*, unsigned int, int) (ip_proto.h:803)
==36720==    by 0x5BE8B2: UDP_CKSUM(unsigned char const*, udphdr const*, unsigned int) (ip_proto.h:970)
==36720==    by 0x5BD46A: dpisim::DPIsimPacket::computeChecksum_(unsigned char*, int) (DPIsimPacket.cc:990)
==36720==    by 0x5BD20E: dpisim::DPIsimPacket::computeChecksum() (DPIsimPacket.cc:939)
==36720==    by 0x5BB577: dpisim::DPIsimPacket::readPacket_(unsigned int) (DPIsimPacket.cc:349)
==36720==    by 0x5BB0D3: dpisim::DPIsimPacket::initialize(pcap_pkthdr const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int) (DPIsimPacket.cc:225)
==36720==    by 0x5BA5DB: dpisim::DPIsimPacket::DPIsimPacket(pcap_pkthdr const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int) (DPIsimPacket.cc:42)
==36720==    by 0x5DF70A: dpisim::DPIsimPacketManager::manipulatePacket(unsigned int, pcap_pkthdr*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int) (DPIsimPacketManager.cc:102)
==36720==    by 0x5ADFE4: dpisim::DPIsimTracePcap::run() (DPIsimTracePcap.cc:134)
==36720==    by 0x5DED12: boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>::operator()(dpisim::DPIsimTrace*) const (mem_fn_template.hpp:49)
==36720==    by 0x5DEBB5: void boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<dpisim::DPIsimTrace*> >::operator()<boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>, boost::_bi::list0>(boost::_bi::type<void>, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>&, boost::_bi::list0&, int) (bind.hpp:255)
==36720==    by 0x5DEAE8: boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<dpisim::DPIsimTrace*> > >::operator()() (bind_template.hpp:20)
==36720==  Address 0x7df53ac is 12 bytes after a block of size 48 alloc'd
==36720==    at 0x4A08982: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:385)
==36720==    by 0x5BB02C: dpisim::DPIsimPacket::initialize(pcap_pkthdr const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int) (DPIsimPacket.cc:215)
==36720==    by 0x5BA5DB: dpisim::DPIsimPacket::DPIsimPacket(pcap_pkthdr const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int) (DPIsimPacket.cc:42)
==36720==    by 0x5DF70A: dpisim::DPIsimPacketManager::manipulatePacket(unsigned int, pcap_pkthdr*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int) (DPIsimPacketManager.cc:102)
==36720==    by 0x5ADFE4: dpisim::DPIsimTracePcap::run() (DPIsimTracePcap.cc:134)
==36720==    by 0x5DED12: boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>::operator()(dpisim::DPIsimTrace*) const (mem_fn_template.hpp:49)
==36720==    by 0x5DEBB5: void boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<dpisim::DPIsimTrace*> >::operator()<boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>, boost::_bi::list0>(boost::_bi::type<void>, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>&, boost::_bi::list0&, int) (bind.hpp:255)
==36720==    by 0x5DEAE8: boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<dpisim::DPIsimTrace*> > >::operator()() (bind_template.hpp:20)
==36720==    by 0x5DEA63: boost::detail::thread_data<boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, dpisim::DPIsimTrace>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<dpisim::DPIsimTrace*> > > >::run() (thread.hpp:116)
==36720==    by 0x608DD49: thread_proxy (in /lab/dpi/building-deps/boost/boost_1_59_0/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.59.0)
==36720==    by 0x3D45807AA0: start_thread (in /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so)
==36720==    by 0x3D454E893C: clone (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==36720==
```

Le he estado dando un par de vueltas y no consigo evitar los errores. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Según la documentación de `valgrind`, este tipo de mensajes te puede salir cuando la memoria a la que accedes ha sido liberada previamente.

Comment: ¿Qué parámetros le estás pasando a la función?

Comment: ¿Se puede ver el código de `htons`? Al parecer no hay errores si le quito esa función, de lo contrario no me compila.